# Synchronizing Lotus Notes Calendar with Google Calendar

Tags: sync, lotus-notes, google-calendar

I am working at a client where [Lotus Notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Lotus_Notes) is used. How do I synchronize the Notes calendar (Lotus Notes 7) with [Google Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Calendar) or directly with my iPhone 3GS?

I don't need to synchronize the emails, the calendar entries and tasks are sufficient.

I searched for solutions but couldn't find any proper ones. Preferably, the synchronization would be automatic on a regular basis but it's also OK if I have to trigger it manually. Please do not suggest solutions involving Outlook since I cannot install that here.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this helps:

Have a look at http://lngooglecalsync.sourceforge.net . It's a project I have started for the exact purpose you are asking for. Automation will come next week with the next beta version.

Hope this helped.

regards
Shin

Answer (score 2):

Intogoogle- The best there is!

The apps listed above either cost a lot, or have lots of issues..This one works like a breeze

http://sourceforge.net/projects/lntogoogle/

Answer (score 1):

Try AweSync beta: http://awesync.com
It is capable of syncing most of the event types, you're welcome to participate in beta-testing.

Comment: thanks Dmitry. I tried AweSync and it works pretty fine! Great tool!

Comment: Always a little sketched out storing my creds with a tool like this without being able to see the source code. The software seems to be written well which convinced me to trust it.

Answer (score 0):

[Sync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lngooglecalsync/)
<- Give this one a try.

Gerard.

Comment: Thanks. That only works if you have your notes file available over HTTP. Any other solution if that's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Local mail file support will also be available soon.

Comment: Thanks Shin, I found your project page earlier but couldnt try it until it supports local mail files. Hope this will be available soon. Thanks for your work.

Answer (score 0):

CompanionLink offers a solution that can automatically sync to Google Calendar every hour or so. There's a free trial and the product costs $40.

I have used this successfully to sync to Google Calendar, and I've set my iPhone to sync with Google automatically.

http://www.companionlink.com/products/clg-googlesync/companionlinkforgoogle-lotusnotes.html

Answer (score 0):

Contact your sysadmins and volunteer to test Notes 8.5.1 and (crucially) the mail template that goes with it.
8.5.1 allows you to display your google calendar alongside your Notes one, 8.5.2 will actually suck in the next x days of your google calendar into your Notes one.
Not sure whether it pushes the other way, though, I never tested that.

You could then use your google calendar as your primary, but how well that works depends how much your colleagues use the meeting invites and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried AweSync, works absolutely perfect!!