# Syncronize Lotus Notes Calendar to Google Calendar on an Apple Mac (OSX)

Tags: macos, mac, sync, lotus-notes, google-calendar

My company using Lotus Notes for calendar end mail just implemented the policy to use MacBooks for work. This is great in general, the only thing I am missing is a tool to sync my Lotus Notes (LN) calendar data to Google Calendar (GC). I need a one way synchronization, from LN to GC, but a two way solution is fine too. If possible, the tool should sync to a dedicated configurable calendar within GC, to avoid mixing my personal and work calendar items. This way I could toggle my synced work calendar items on/off in GC.

I am aware about the [same discussion on windows platform](https://superuser.com/questions/24536/synchronizing-lotus-notes-calendar-with-google-calendar). My question is specific for Mac OSX!

Answer (score 0):

I already tried [PIM Syncer](http://pimsyncer.com/), which was promissing, as it is a Lotus Notes application / database, so it does not need an external program to work, but runs inside Lotus Notes. Unfortunately I was not able to configure it properly, it hangs when I try to retrieve the list of my Google Calendar calendars, and than I have to kill the APP:(. This symptom was listed in their FAQ section, but the prescribed solution did not work for me, so I tried to contact them, without luck,.. no response came so far.

Also my colleague managed to configure it to work, but unfortunately after syncing, Google Calendar did send out a ton invites to all invitees in all synced items, which was an unexpected, totally wrong, and quit awkward.

So PIM Syncer kinda failed for me.